# Sharepoint 2013 : SharePoint designer Workflow gets canceled

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

Workflow is getting cancelled on the first stage,

I have not started workflow with System account, as well User profile is created and sych

getting following error:

```
RequestorId: 393c529a-08f0-6583-e92d-3cdba2e61a14. Details: System.ArgumentException:    AssignedTo at 
Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at
System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, 
ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at  
System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you add some more details to the question like what fields you have in the list and against which field the workflow is getting initiated,etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply scenarios is, In list having one column of reported by with allow multiple selection, people picker. I want to send an email to all the people in this column. Workflow is workflow is working fine if I have only one user in the column, however it gets canceled when more then one user entry is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given proper permission to the user and issue got resolved for me.

Edit:

Finally nailed it by following steps:

1. Be sure User profile synchronization is started.
2. The user by whom you are logged is available in User Profile list. ( In my case it was not, created new profile for the current logged in user and make sure, you are not running workflow with SharePoint system user. Please create a new user in Active directory, and using this user, create/provision workfow
         3. Final step full synchronization of User Profile Application.

you can find the my blog on it: http://anujabhojani.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-gets-canceled.html

Comment: I met the same problem,you say that you have resolved this issue by promote permission to user.so I have some question. 1. Which user should promote? does user start the workflow or task assigned to? 2. What kind of permission you should give? Is the workflow manager permission or SharePoint permission or sql permission? Can you give me more suggestion about this issue?thanks very much!

Comment: decribed in my blog post: http://anujabhojani.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-gets-canceled.html